# Missing 2D density layer in ggplot facet

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am attempting to generate a faceted ggplot that includes a points layer and a 2D density layer using two measures: *valence* and *energy*. I'm able to create a plot without my desired facet, however when I facet by *artist* the 2D density is missing from one of the frames.

Here is a glimpse of my data:

```
head(df)
#>   artist valence energy  song
#>   <chr>    <dbl>  <dbl> <int>
#> 1 A        0.465  0.765     1
#> 2 A        0.407  0.841     2
#> 3 A        0.279  0.711     3
#> 4 A        0.398  0.302     4
#> 5 A        0.471  0.862     5
#> 6 A        0.387  0.843     6
```

I'm able to successfully plot points and 2D-density without faceting:

```
library(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot(df, aes(x = valence, y = energy)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0, 1)) + 
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 1)) + 
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept = 0.5)) + 
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept = 0.5)) + 
  geom_density_2d()
p
```

[image: 2d density without facet]

But when I facet by *artist* I get an error message and artist 'C' is missing the density layer:

```
p + facet_wrap(vars(artist))
#> Warning: stat_contour(): Zero contours were generated
#> Warning in min(x): no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
#> Warning in max(x): no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
```

[image: 2d density with facet]

I'm confused why I'm getting this error message because my two measures consist of values between 0 and 1 and there wasn't an error when I plotted the two measures without a facet. Other variations where I use `stat_density_2d()` and `stat_contour()` in place of `geom_density_2d()` haven't worked either. I've also tried expanding the x and y limits but that didn't fix the error either.

#### Data:

```
df <- structure(list(artist = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", 
"B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B"), valence = c(0.341, 
0.387, 0.586, 0.598, 0.385, 0.465, 0.33, 0.646, 0.284, 0.381, 
0.487, 0.55, 0.173, 0.385, 0.35, 0.0424, 0.84, 0.447, 0.129, 
0.0391, 0.209, 0.35, 0.65, 0.505, 0.745, 0.434, 0.357, 0.258, 
0.836, 0.382), energy = c(0.851, 0.843, 0.6, 0.892, 0.857, 0.765, 
0.699, 0.755, 0.841, 0.914, 0.124, 0.857, 0.424, 0.379, 0.694, 
0.446, 0.954, 0.85, 0.229, 0.79, 0.893, 0.838, 0.855, 0.829, 
0.932, 0.907, 0.932, 0.764, 0.949, 0.906), song = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 
9L, 10L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L)), row.names = c(NA, 
-30L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is simply that in ggplot v3.3.2 the 2d density is binned the same way across all your facets. In your third facet, the density isn't high enough to get into the second bin, so there is no contour line. You can see this by increasing the bins to 50:

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df, aes(x = valence, y = energy)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0, 1)) + 
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 1)) + 
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept = 0.5)) + 
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept = 0.5)) + 
  stat_density_2d(bins = 50) +
  facet_grid(~artist)
```

[image]

Now the problem is that the third panel looks good, but the first two don't. You could fix this by making two `stat_density_2d`, one of which has a conditional alpha value:

```r
ggplot(df, aes(x = valence, y = energy)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0, 1)) + 
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 1)) + 
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept = 0.5)) + 
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept = 0.5)) +
  stat_density2d() +
  stat_density_2d(aes(alpha = as.numeric(as.factor(artist)) %/% 3), bins = 50) + 
  scale_alpha_identity() +
  facet_grid(~artist)
```

[image]

Of course, the bins are no longer showing equivalent density across all the panels, but these are effectively the choices you have.

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = valence, y = energy)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0, 1)) + 
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 1)) + 
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept = 0.5)) + 
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept = 0.5)) + 
  geom_density_2d() + facet_wrap(~artist, scales = 'free')
```

[image]

Comment: What version of ggplot are you using Reza?

Comment: packageVersion('ggplot2') -> ‘3.3.0’

Comment: I'm using ggplot2 3.3.2 and this doesn't work for me.

Comment: Same here, it doesn't work. ggplot2 3.3.2. The scales = 'free' shouldn't change anything I believe.